# Event handling in libgdx not working as expected

Tags: java, libgdx

I've been learning about libgdx recently. In the process of following the instructions on their libgdx wiki I ran into some problems.

Specifically in the GameScreen class at the 99th line I changed the code inside so that it goes back to the previous screen (MainMenuScreen class) and yes you see when the mouse is pressed it worked (I mean go back to the screen before ) but a very very short time after, the screen AUTOMATICALLY switches to the GameScreen class (like I click the mouse once but it makes me 1 more redundant task). I guess when I click on the GameScreen screen  it did the code in the if statement on line 99 to go to MainMenuScreen screen. In that screen at line 32 I guess it was true after I got to this screen because when I change the key is listened  then it works fine (only converts once). I was intending to try implementing InputProcessor on each screen class but now I'm avoiding it for some reason. Can someone give me some advice recommend.Thank you

Here is the source code for the MainMenuScreen class.

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;
//import com.mygdx.game.Drop;
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen {

final Drop game;
OrthographicCamera camera;

public MainMenuScreen(final Drop gam) {
    game = gam;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    ScreenUtils.clear(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);

    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    game.batch.begin();
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Welcome to Drop!!! ", 100, 150);
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Tap anywhere to begin!", 100, 100);
    game.batch.end();

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) { //I guess right after switching to this screen this conditional sentence was true before
        game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
        dispose();
    }
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void show() {
}

@Override
public void hide() {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
}
}
```

Here is source code for the GameScreen class

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import java.util.Iterator;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;

public class GameScreen implements Screen {

final Drop game;

Texture dropImage;
Texture bucketImage;
//Sound dropSound;
//Music rainMusic;
OrthographicCamera camera;
Rectangle bucket;
Array<Rectangle> raindrops;
long lastDropTime;
int dropsGathered;

public GameScreen(final Drop gam) {
    this.game = gam;

    // load the images for the droplet and the bucket, 64x64 pixels each
    dropImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("drop.png"));
    bucketImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bucket.png"));

    // load the drop sound effect and the rain background "music"
    //dropSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("drop.wav"));
    //rainMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("rain.mp3"));
    //rainMusic.setLooping(true);

    // create the camera and the SpriteBatch
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);

    // create a Rectangle to logically represent the bucket
    bucket = new Rectangle();
    bucket.x = 800 / 2 - 64 / 2; // center the bucket horizontally
    bucket.y = 20; // bottom left corner of the bucket is 20 pixels above
                    // the bottom screen edge
    bucket.width = 64;
    bucket.height = 64;

    // create the raindrops array and spawn the first raindrop
    raindrops = new Array<Rectangle>();
    spawnRaindrop();

}

private void spawnRaindrop() {
    Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
    raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800 - 64);
    raindrop.y = 480;
    raindrop.width = 64;
    raindrop.height = 64;
    raindrops.add(raindrop);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // clear the screen with a dark blue color. The
    // arguments to clear are the red, green
    // blue and alpha component in the range [0,1]
    // of the color to be used to clear the screen.
    ScreenUtils.clear(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);

    // tell the camera to update its matrices.
    camera.update();

    // tell the SpriteBatch to render in the
    // coordinate system specified by the camera.
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    // begin a new batch and draw the bucket and
    // all drops
    game.batch.begin();
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Drops Collected: " + dropsGathered, 0, 480);
    game.batch.draw(bucketImage, bucket.x, bucket.y);
    for (Rectangle raindrop : raindrops) {
        game.batch.draw(dropImage, raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
    }
    game.batch.end();

    // process user input
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) { //This conditional works fine
    /*  Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
        touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        camera.unproject(touchPos);
        bucket.x = touchPos.x - 64 / 2;
    */
    game.setScreen(new MainMenuSceen(game)); //Screen switch
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT))
        bucket.x -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT))
        bucket.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    // make sure the bucket stays within the screen bounds
    if (bucket.x < 0)
        bucket.x = 0;
    if (bucket.x > 800 - 64)
        bucket.x = 800 - 64;

    // check if we need to create a new raindrop
    if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000)
        spawnRaindrop();

    // move the raindrops, remove any that are beneath the bottom edge of
    // the screen or that hit the bucket. In the later case we play back
    // a sound effect as well.
    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Rectangle raindrop = iter.next();
        raindrop.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (raindrop.y + 64 < 0)
            iter.remove();
        if (raindrop.overlaps(bucket)) {
            dropsGathered++;
            //dropSound.play();
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void show() {
    // start the playback of the background music
    // when the screen is shown
    //rainMusic.play();
}

@Override
public void hide() {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    dropImage.dispose();
    bucketImage.dispose();
    //dropSound.dispose();
    //rainMusic.dispose();
}

}
```

Here is source for Drop class

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Drop extends Game {

SpriteBatch batch;
BitmapFont font;

public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    // Use LibGDX's default Arial font.
    font = new BitmapFont();
    this.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));
}

public void render() {
    super.render(); // important!
}

public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    font.dispose();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis of the problem seems correct to me. The method `Gdx.input.isTouched()` will immediately return true, if the screen is still being touched after you changed to the main menu.

Also you the solution that you already tried seems correct:

> I was intending to try implementing InputProcessor on each screen class

When using an `InputProcessor` you will get one event (the method call to `touchDown` or `touchUp`) when the screen is touched, and don't need to pull the touch event using the `isTouched` method.

A problem when implementing `InputProcessor` with both classes probably is, that you can only set one to be the input processor of the game using the method `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor`. (When setting the second input processor, the first one is removed).
A solution to this problem is the [InputMultiplexer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html). You can add this multiplexer as the input processor of the game (using `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer)`) and then add your input processors (the main menu and game objects) to this multiplexer: `multiplexer.addProcessor(mainMenu)` or `((InputMultiplexer) Gdx.input.getInputProcessor()).addProcessor(game)`.

This way you can handle touch events instead of pulling the touched state in both of your classes.

Comment: If you have other problems with the `InputProcessor` you can edit you question and we can try to solve it :)